# Как по клику убрать/добавить атрибут "muted" в <video>

Tags: javascript, видео, атрибуты

Написал вот такой код. Не работает. Подскажите что исправить.

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
var volume = document.getElementById("volume");

volume.onclick = function() {
  if (video.hasAttribute('muted')) {
    video.removeAttribute('muted');
  } else {
    video.addAttribute('muted');
  }
};
```

```html
<video id="video" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="img/video.mp4" type="video/webm" />
</video>
<button id="volume">Звук</button>
```

Comment: можно увидеть html?

Comment: @AuRoom Добавил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
var volume = document.getElementById("volume");

volume.addEventListener('click', function() {
    video.muted = (video.muted == false) ? true : false;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду применять в следующих проектах.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...)

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут `muted` является логическим атрибутом. Достаточно сделать так:

```
volume.addEventListener('click', function () {
    video.muted = !video.muted;         
})
```

Comment: Повторный клик почему-то не работает.

Comment: `volume.click = function () {

 if (video.muted = true) {
     video.muted = false;
 } else {
     video.muted = true;
      }

}`

Comment: Поправил ответ, попробуйте снова

Comment: скопировал ваш код, но выключение звука не работает, тоесть то что по else идёт.

Comment: а не проще сделать в `if ` конструкцию `video.muted = !video.muted`, тогда ветка else не понадобится

Comment: Действительно, не подумал об этом =D